# In MongoDB how to use "$expr" with an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the below document:

```
{
 MyField1: 'A',
 MyArray: [
  {
   MyArrayField1: 'C';
  },
  {
   MyArrayField1: 'A';
  }
 ]
}
```

How can I select all documents in `MyArray` an object with `MyArrayField1 = MyField1`?

I tried

> db.find({$expr: {$eq: ["$MyArray.MyArrayField1",
>   "$MyField1"]}})

even

> db.find({$expr: {$eq: ["$MyArray.MyArrayField1",
>   "A"]}})

but it's not working :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) operator

```
db.col.find({
    $expr: {
        $in: [ "$MyField1", "$MyArray.MyArrayField1" ]
    }
})
```

In this case `MyArray.MyArrayField1` will represent an array of two values `A` and `C`

Comment: {
        $lookup:{
            from: "dealer",
            let: { codes: "$dealer_codes_exist" },
            pipeline: [
                { 
                    $match:{ 
                        $expr:{ 
                            $and:[
                                { $nin: [ "$code",  "$$codes" ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                { $project: { code: 1, _id: 0, name: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "dealers"
        }
    }

Comment: @AbdulMoiz can you open a separate question and link it here? Thanks